# Definition of the outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set. By definition, for every sequence of sets (disjoint or not), an outer measure $\theta:\mathcal{P}X\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ is a monotic, countably subadditive (hence subadditive) function which vanishes at $0$.

We then have four possibilities:

- $A\cap B=\emptyset$ implies $\theta(A\cup B)=\theta A+\theta B$ (additivity)
- $A\cap B=\emptyset$ implies $\theta(A\cup B)<\theta A+\theta B$ (e.g. Bernstein set)
- $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$ implies $\theta(A\cup B)<\theta A+\theta B$ (quite intuitive)

My question is how to interpret the last possibility:

- $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$ implies $\theta(A\cup B)=\theta A+\theta B$

Is it as well a case of nonmeasurability?

If not, could anybody provide me with a simple example?

Comment: $\theta (A) = 0$ for all $A \subset X$?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a case of non measurability: take the lebesgue outer measure and take $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [1,2]$.

$A \cup B = [0,2]$ and $A \cap B = \{1\} \neq \emptyset$ but clearly the outer measure of the union is the sum of the outer measure and both $A$ and $B$ will be measurable in the sense of Caratheodory (or in any sense, they are intervals! :D )